# Why is my ember routing not used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm starting developing with Ember using [`ember-rails`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails) with Rails 4.1.

With the following routes defined:

```
MyApp.Router.reopen({
    rootURL: '/mycontroller/'
})
MyApp.Router.map () ->
    this.route('welcome')
```

When I access the URL `http://mysite/mycontroller/welcome`, the `welcome` template is not rendered but the `index` one is.

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.8.0 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.11 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1 
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
Attempting URL transition to / 
generated -> route:application Object {fullName: "route:application"} ember.js?   body=1:15359
generated -> route:index Object {fullName: "route:index"} 
Transition #0: application: calling beforeModel hook 
Transition #0: application: calling deserialize hook 
Transition #0: application: calling afterModel hook 
Transition #0: index: calling beforeModel hook 
Transition #0: index: calling deserialize hook 
Transition #0: index: calling afterModel hook 
Transition #0: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition. 
generated -> controller:application Object {fullName: "controller:application"} 
Could not find "application" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:application"} 
generated -> controller:index Object {fullName: "controller:index"} 
Rendering index with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember307> Object {fullName: "view:index"} 
Transitioned into 'index' 
Transition #0: TRANSITION COMPLETE.
```

How come my route is not understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Ember routing expects a hash symbol in your URL before the route. To navigate to your `welcome` route the URL should be `http://mysite/mycontroller/#/welcome`.

If you don't like this behavior it can be disabled by having Ember interact with a browser's history API like so:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

You could then use the URL `http://mysite/mycontroller/welcome` as expected.

[Here are the docs on Ember URL types](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/)